# What policy does the party "True Finns" (Perussuomalaiset) propose w.r.t. wolves?

Tags: finland, hunting

In the Nordic countries, the situation of predators in nature is often a hotly debated issue. Green parties, and other parties with a strongly urban voter-base, often hold the point of view that predators are part of nature and that a healthy population should be allowed to exist. Parties with a strong rural voter-base often propose a strong policy of hunting predators such as wolves, arguing that their existance makes life for people in rural areas difficult or impossible.

In The Netherlands (not a nordic country), the nationalist conservative party [is critical of hunting](http://www.nu.nl/nieuws/2888611/dierenpartij-wil-plezierjagen-verbieden.html), whereas the Swedish nationalist conservative party [supports a strong reduction in the number of wolves](http://helahalsingland.se/ljusdal/1.5247314-sd-vill-ha-farre-vargar), via hunting. The parties are of different nature and perhaps their respective points of view are rather motivated by [populism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Populism) rather than a particular ideology.

What is the point of view of the Finnish nationalist conservative political party True Finns (Finnish: Perussuomalaiset, Swedish: Sannfinländarna) with regard to hunting and the presence of predators in nature?

Comment: I would propose avoiding "extreme-right" labels. Leaving aside the subjunctives of "right" label, your own political positions may also seem "extreme" to someone, I'm sure you would not like to be labeled as "extremist".

Answer (score 3):

It is not a major concern of the party, however in a [published summary of party positions in 2011](http://www.perussuomalaiset.fi/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Perussuomalaisten_eduskuntavaaliohjelma_2011-english_summary_2.0.pdf) it states

> Recreational hunting opportunities must be safeguarded

and, though it is not directly about hunting, it reflects the parties position on animal welfare:

> Fur farming with humane practices should be supported.

The general attitude is that practices that are identified as being culturally "Finnish" should be supported, this includes the right of recreational hunting. While wolves are not mentioned in this source, it can be assumed that this would include hunting of wolves.

As a Euroseptic party they would reject the right of the EU to create laws on animal welfare (or any other issue) that apply to Finland